# can web2py support RESTful api calls? if so any pointers on how to build one?I

Tags: iphone, python, cocoa, restful-authentication, web2py

I want to configure a simple webapplication to support an iphone app to connect with it in RESTFUL ways. Initially have a user login session enabled from the iphone to the web app. I'd like the iphone app to send a NSURL call to the webapp, with user and password and have the webapp respond if the suer exists or not. Pretty simple. And I want to do it with web2py. Is this possible? Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should post it to web2py group on google groups.

web2py@googlegroups.com

Comment: Or via the web interface: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old now, but Massimo recently posted a [video demonstrating a new experimental RESTful API for web2py](http://vimeo.com/21133657). See also the Google groups posting "v[ideo about new RESTful APIs](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/web2py/gcqEcXIo7RI/discussion)" .